# Extract a string from within a tag Python

Tags: python, html

'''script type="7b065748e865a1f7340d2b51-text/javascript">

```
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
        //Load all the variables            
        var player = [];
        var playerid = 0;
        var mode = "none";
        var ep_identifier = "dvPrKEDsjzz7SJdbqRWHwfh1juZlbFX09EGP21HVhh0dqbsen3XrP2nAav4sV8mwTHJjcgUyqeluWuBr4Rf8tzbfgj9jr39weaK70pVjuSqLJgHRyS+DQuwU79srG66hpISzJkK2DjvnnjDi7qizoqwCqLhRmVIdHx930uU8n+Ab08KScv3HhJf9L7B+Y8ALzGjJCjk8ce11Izruz6CdkpbtCQZo8/OrSHqLw6UKjhwlEV/tBJlpz1jcXf7V6S2N";
                    var VidStreaming = "https://gogo-play.net/load.php?id=MTU4MjAz&title=Jouran%3A+The+Princess+of+Snow+and+Blood&typesub=SUB&sub=&cover=Y292ZXIvam91cmFuLXRoZS1wcmluY2Vzcy1vZi1zbm93LWFuZC1ibG9vZC5wbmc=";
        var VidHLS = "";'''
```

**How do i extract "https://gogo-play.net/load.php?id=MTU4MjAz&title=Jouran%3A+The+Princess+of+Snow+and+Blood&typesub=SUB&sub=&cover=Y292ZXIvam91cmFuLXRoZS1wcmluY2Vzcy1vZi1zbm93LWFuZC1ibG9vZC5wbmc=""

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Gexion!  Could you specify what exactly you mean by "extract"? Do you want to download the link content? Also please tell us what you have tried so far so that we can help you better. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if what you mean is the link then you can use Regex with this syntax

```
"(https://.+)"
```

for example:

```
import re
result = re.findall(r" '(https://.+)' ", the_string_to_extract_from)
```

to extract it with 2 conditions:

1. the start of the link is https://
2. the link is contained in " "

You may want to provide more information on this problem.